# Getting "Release: The following signatures were invalid" on local repo

Tags: apt, server, 18.04

We just installed an Ubuntu 18.04 Server VM to see if our Chef configuration would work on this new distro.

On a separate VM, we have a local apt mirror for this release:

```
# tree
.
├── extra
│   ├── binary-amd64
│   │   ├── Packages
│   │   └── Packages.gz
│   └── binary-i386
│       ├── Packages
│       └── Packages.gz
├── Release
└── Release.gpg

3 directories, 6 files
```

We signed the `Release` file using this command:

```
/usr/bin/gpg -abs -o Release.gpg Release
```

The signature seems to be ok after this:

```
# LANG=C gpg --verify /var/www/html/ubuntu-local/dists/bionic/Release.gpg /var/www/html/ubuntu-local/dists/bionic/Release
gpg: Signature made mar 29 may 2018 13:03:12 WEST using RSA key ID 271AFAF4
gpg: Good signature from "... <...@...>"
```

On the client side, we've imported the `271AFAF4` key:

```
# LANG=C apt-key list
/etc/apt/trusted.gpg
--------------------
pub   rsa2048 2014-10-27 [SC]
      0F11 1A77 EE05 C406 2691  FC74 1794 5F7F 271A FAF4
uid           [ unknown] ... <...@...>
```

The repo definition file on the client side is:

```
deb      "http://localrepo/ubuntu-local" bionic extra
```

However, each time I run `apt-get update` I get:

```
W: GPG error: http://localrepo/ubuntu-local bionic Release: The following signatures were invalid: 0F111A77EE05C4062691FC7417945F7F271AFAF4
E: The repository 'http://localrepo/ubuntu-local bionic Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

However, as you can see above the signature is correct. As a side note, the very same configuration worked on `xenial` (replacing `bionic` by `xenial` in the repo config file), and I also tried to add the `xenial` repo on the `bionic` VM with the same result.

I have seen other answers but this seems not to be a duplicate of them.

What am I missing?

Comment: You might find [this](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/apt-secure.8.html) useful.

Comment: @ElderGeek these are basically the steps that I've followed, it's still failing though.

Comment: basically? or exactly? Your output indicates that the signature is invalid. Everything else happens due to that. I would begin by generating a new one .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [E: The repository 'http//archive.canonical.com precise Release' is not signed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1120194/e-the-repository-http-archive-canonical-com-precise-release-is-not-signed)

Answer (score 0):

Try using this -

```
/usr/bin/gpg -bs -o Release.gpg Release
```

Instead of this -

```
/usr/bin/gpg -abs -o Release.gpg Release
```

Notice the "-a" difference.

From gpg manpage -

> -a --armor
>   Create ASCII armored output.  The default is to create the binary OpenPGP format.

According to [this](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianRepository/UseThirdParty) -

> ...The reason why we avoid ASCII-armored files is that they cannot be used directly by SecureApt..

---

**NOTE:**

If the above method doesn't work, as an additional step along with the above mentioned method, try adding these two lines to the **~/.gnupg/gpg.conf** file -

```
cert-digest-algo SHA256
digest-algo SHA256
```